# Trouble with proof for exact linear ODE's

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a linear ODE:

$$a_n(x)\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}+ \cdots +a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + a_0(x)y = f(x)$$

If the ODE is exact, the LHS can be written as:

$$a_n(x)\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}+ \cdots +a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + a_0(x)y = \frac{d}{dx} \biggl[b_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+b_0(x)y \biggl] \tag{1}$$

I want to prove that if $(1)$ holds, then:

$$a_0(x)-a_1'(x)+a_2''(x)-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}a_n^{(n)}(x)=0$$

The prime denotes differentiation with respect to $x$

I'm really stumped on this one and couldn't find any help on google.

Any hints or reference would be appreciated

Comment: I suspect as a first step you should differentiate the $b_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+b_0(x)y$ so that you can more easily compare the RHS with the LHS. What do you get? *Hint:* product rule.

Comment: i get $$b_{n-1}'(x) \frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + b_{n-1}(x) \frac{d^n y}{dx^n} + \cdots + b_{0}'(x)y + b_0(x) \frac{dy}{dx}$$

So rearranging,

$$b_{n-1}(x) \frac{d^n y}{dx^n} + b_{n-1}'(x) \frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} +  \cdots + b_0(x) \frac{dy}{dx} + b_{0}'(x)y $$

So this implies that:

$$a_n(x) = b_{n-1}(x) \\ a_{n-1}(x) = b_{n-1}'(x) \\ \vdots \\ a_1(x) = b_0(x) \\ a_0(x) = b_0'(x)$$

Ah! So:

$$a_0(x) - a_1'(x) = b_0'(x) - \frac{d}{dx}(b_0(x)) = 0 \\ \vdots \\
a_{n-1}(x) - a_n(x) = b_{n-1}'(x) - \frac{d}{dx}(b_{n-1}(x)) = 0$$

Comment: I disagree. When you differentiate $b_{n-2},$ you'll get both a $y^{(n-1)}$ and a $y^{(n-2)}$ term. I would recommend filling the "insides" of your differentiation a bit more. I would expect the inside $a_i$'s to equal the sum of two different $b_j$'s.

Comment: Also, please add this work to your question, and don't do all this in the comments.

Comment: sure i will write it as an answer and credit you

Comment: You're not there, yet! This is still part of the question.

Comment: @AdrianKeister yup i edited the answer do take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer credited to [Adrian Keister](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30813/adrian-keister)

$$RHS: \frac{d}{dx} \biggl[b_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+b_0(x)y \biggl] = 
\\ b_{n-1}'(x) \frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + b_{n-1}(x) \frac{d^n y}{dx^n} + \\ b_{n-2}'(x) \frac{d^{n-2}y}{dx^{n-2}} + b_{n-2} \frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + \\
b_{n-3}'(x) \frac{d^{n-3}y}{dx^{n-3}} + b_{n-3} \frac{d^{n-2}y}{dx^{n-2}}+ \\ \vdots  \\b_2'(x) \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + b_2(x) \frac{d^3 y}{dx^3} +\\ b_1'(x) \frac{dy}{dx} + b_1(x) \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} +\\b_{0}'(x)y + b_0(x) \frac{dy}{dx} \\
$$

From observation:
$$a_n(x) = b_{n-1}(x)\\
a_{n-1}(x) = b_{n-1}'(x)  + b_{n-2}  \\
a_{n-2}(x) = b_{n-2}'(x)  + b_{n-3}  \\ \vdots \\ 
a_2(x) = b_2'(x)  + b_1(x)  \\
a_1(x) = b_1'(x)  +  b_0(x)  \\
a_0(x) = b_{0}'(x) $$

Now we consider the original problem:
$$a_0(x)-a_1'(x)+a_2''(x)-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}a_n^{(n)}(x)= \\ \ \\ 
b_{0}'(x) - [b_1''(x)+b_0'(x)] + [b_2'''(x) + b_1''(x)] + ... = \\ \ \\  0 $$

which we can see the terms cancel out

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: solid. thanks for ur help!